# Slit Experiment in a swimming pool

Tags: waves

Would like to perform double slit experiment in swimming pool.

1. Create waves by dropping pebbles in increasing size up to an actual golf ball. Waves travel to and through aluminum double slit screen.
2. Observe waves on pool bottom and record with video.
3. Observe corresponding wave impacts on pool wall and record..

Am requesting approximate dimensions of slits and distance between. I anticipate wave lengths to be from 1/2 inch to two inches depending upon size of dropped object.

Any advice will be appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: I forget the keywords/names, but there do also exist set-ups to look at shadows of waves in much smaller shallow pans-of-water... maybe in highe-school physics classes? ... which might be more tractable/amenable for your purposes. At least maybe as a warm-up.

Comment: @paulgarrett - I remember those from the late 70's (did I just date myself? sigh). We used them a lot...

Comment: @JonCuster, but/and what were they called?

Comment: [This video might help you?](https://youtu.be/Iuv6hY6zsd0?t=268)